# How to correctly implement the ROS2 architecture (rclcpp, rcl, rmw)

Tags: c++, ros2

I am a beginner with ROS2 and C++ and I can use some help understanding how the architecture of ROS 2 works. I want to implement a QoS-event into a simple chatter program and with my basic knowledge I can make following graph:

CODE (publisher.cpp) ==> RCLCPP(qos_event.cpp) this includes (qos_event.hpp) ==> RCL (event.c) this includes (event.h) ==> RMW (event.c) this includes (event.h) ==> DDS

I have the following questions:

1. If I understand it right, header files are used as some kind of library. So if you include them in your program you can use all the functions you want. This means I don't need to use this code in my program but I only need to implement those functions? Are the following files: qos_event.cpp / rcl event.c / rmw event.c examples of code that I can use into my own program?
2. The Quality of Service (QoS) settings are declared in the Ros middleware (rmw). If I want to use one of those events, can I just directly use the rmw/event.h header file or do I need to respect the architecture and is it only possible to implement rclcpp code in your program?

Answer (score 0):

1) Generally header files have declarations of functions that you can use and .c or .cpp files have the definition of them, showing how the function actually is implemented. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration) may be a good starting point for that. In order to use this functions in your executable or library, you have to add these dependencies via CMakeLists.txt and package.xml(a whole new world for c++ beginners).

2)  About this ... I would recommend checking [this git](https://github.com/ros2/demos/tree/master/quality_of_service_demo) from ROS2 and studying how these functions were used.

Usually people say to study c++ before using the ROS Framework, this is a really good advice.